# Python Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'picamera'

Tags: python, django, numpy, raspberry-pi, picamera

I'm making my first Django-based web page, and trying to live stream video from my raspberry pi to said web page, but for some reason, I can't import the 'picamera'-module in Django... I have written a script that outputs the camera-feed, and it works fine when I run it outside of the server, but when I import my camera-script to views.py, I get the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'picamera'`. Does anyone know why? All the other modules I'm using works fine both in and outside of Django. Importing my own modules also works fine.

I'm certain that I have installed the picamera-module (https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/) correctly, I even tried removing and reinstalling it. I got the same error when trying to import NumPy(https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)...

I am using a virtual environment. I don't know if that may be a factor, but I thought I'd mention it, just in case.

Eternally grateful to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try "sudo pip install picamera" in terminal.
If you are using python 3 try"sudo pip3 install picamera"instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've already tried that, though, makes no difference...

Comment: Well,make sure your os is up to date:)